# Import CSV from AWS S3 instance to Numpy

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, numpy, csv, amazon-s3

I've been trying to directly read a csv file from AWS S3 to numpy. I've used:

```
s3 = boto3.client(service_name = 's3')

def s3_read(filename):
    s3_obj = s3.get_object(Bucket = 'bucket-name', Key = filename)
    body = s3_obj['Body']
    return body.read()
```

as an attempt to pull the data but I'm running into an issue of formatting from AWS that I don't know how to handle.

When I print out the data that is being returned from that there is a weird header before the data:

**b{\n "name":"filename",\n "data":{\n "type":"Buffer,\n "data:[\n 114,\n 97,...]}}**

So there's a bunch of \n's and the weird header. Would this have something to do with the way I uploaded the file to AWS or is there something I'm messing up with the reading of the file?

Answer (score 4):

`body.read()` returns bytes.

```
import json
j = json.loads(s3_obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'))
```

`decode` will turn bytes to string, `json.loads` will parse the string to dictionary.